# Raspberry PI to PC communication

Tags: usb, wifi, communication

I am thinking of using Raspberry Pi to share Internet from a PC.

The Raspberry Pi would have a Wi-Fi module which would be running in AD-HOC mode. The Raspberry Pi would be connected to a PC through a USB cable. The PC is the only device connected to the Internet.

I plan to use my laptop to connect to the Pi on AD-HOC. The Pi would route all my traffic through the USB cable to the PC. The PC would route the traffic to its original destination and return the results back to me through the Pi.

The main problem I have with this scenario is the Pi talking to the computer through USB.

What I want to know is if my plan is possible/practical or impossible/impractical. If it is possible, would the PC host need elevated privileges to talk to the Pi through USB?

Comment: Are you using WiFi or USB to connect between the two? Clarify your intention. If you are going to physically connect the two, why not just use a crossover Ethernet cable?

Comment: I think the best way is USB-Serial converter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Serial to USB connection for your plan. I'm using Serial->USB converter for debug messages and login via serial line. There are many information about serial to USB connection in raspberrypi.stackexchange.com answers.

At [this page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) there is an information about network connection with pppd through Serial->USB cable.

- Buy an PL2303 Serial-USB converter
- Connect your PC-RPi via serial.
- Run pppd from PC to connect Rpi.