# Using the WiFi on Raspberry from Windows Embedded XP

Tags: wifi

this topic is totally out of my comfort zone. I have ordered some Raspberry PI books to help me bring me up to speed but I would like to ask whether it is possible to connect Windows Embedded XP to Raspberry (assuming I use a crossover cable), write an app for Windows XP but use the internet connection available on the Raspberry device.

I envisage the Raspberry  device will have a WiFi dongle attached to it.

Is this scenario possible at all?  I need to do this programmatically and not by user intervention.

Comment: I just found this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10054/raspberry-pi-to-pc-communication?rq=1 will this be the way to go?

Comment: You haven't exactly said so, but I assume you want to connect the XP system to the Raspberry via Ethernet and connect the Raspberry to a router with an internet connection via WiFi. In that case, you'll just need to create a network bridge between the ethernet and WiFi interfaces on the Raspberry.

Comment: Hi, thanks fro replying. There is to be no router involved re: "assuming I use a cross-over cable" I have not got the hardware through yet but they had told me that the Raspberry will connect to Windows XP (via an emulator) and that the Raspberry will have a wifi dongle attached to it. If it was using a router then it would be easy to do a connection using the bridge methodology...

Comment: If you don't have a router, what else will be providing the WiFi the Raspberry will connect to? *"via an emulator"* -- what kind of emulator? It would be really helpful if you could update your question with some more information about the hardware you will be using.

Comment: Like I said  I do not know the hardware. I also said I would be using a wifi dongle. I wanted to know the PRINCIPLE of whether it can be done.#

Comment: That depends largely on your setup, so I can't give you much advice without knowing some more details about it. You can easily bridge two network interfaces on Linux (even Windows can do that with a reasonable amount of effort), but you'll need a WiFi dongle for which there are driver for Linux on an ARM processor, and you will need to know (and perhaps tell us) what kind of cross-over cable you want to use -- as I said, I'm guessing it will be an ethernet cable, but there are also cross-over cables for RS232, as well as other interfaces.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your time in this. I share your frustration in not know the hardware specifics. I had told my line manager I really need the physical devices in front of me but they said they will not supply until after xmas.  At least your answer has helped confirm that it should be fairly easy to use the internet in this manner which is a huge relief to me. I know absolutely nothing about Raspberry and it has been over 20 years since i touched Linux. Thanks for the help you have give me :)

Comment: Just keep nagging your manager, I'll be happy to help you with the details when you've got the hardware. ;)

Comment: I was kinda hoping you would say that :) I will be in contact as soon as :)