# Data collection from raspberry pi and send to computer (without using Ethernet or Wifi)

Tags: usb, serial, data-transfer, communication

I use the Pi as sensor data collector and would like to to transmit the data back to software that is installed on my computer (and probably the software will instruct the Pi to perform some tasks, e.g: clear data history, change date time)

For my application, due to some constraints, I am not allow to use Ethernet port as mode of communication/data transfer.

Any other choices I can use? I was thinking USB communication but seems both Pi and PC are USB HOST

I am ok to use either Model A, B+ or Compute Module

**Updated 2 Apr 2015**

1. The Pi is to be mounted with sensors (e.g: DS18S20 temperature sensor) and put inside the chassis of a desktop PC, collecting climate data (e.g: temperature, humidity)
2. The desktop PC has no networking interface (thus, wifi/wireless or Ethernet solutions on Pi is not preferred, favourable choices would be USB or serial)
3. A software on that PC will be automatic interfacing with the Pi to grab sensor data and Pi is to be able alerting the software if any sensor exceeding threshold (e.g: too humid or too hot)

Comment: Is wifi dissallowed as well?  usb wifi dongle?

Comment: @joan Both LAN & wifi are disallowed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raspberry PI to PC communication](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10054/raspberry-pi-to-pc-communication)

Comment: The other obvious choice is using the serial link.  Not quite as fast as USB but it works.

Comment: What's the data rate? What's the distance to bridge? Other constraints (e.g. DC decoupled link)? Any useful recommendation should be based on this.

Comment: serial data rate is acceptable @Ghanima, the Pi is intended to be put inside chassis of a desktop PC and report event to PC software (e.g: temperature, humidity when threshold exceeded). LAN and wifi is not applicable because there is no networking and not allowed

Comment: @joan, using serial link is seems like just doing SSH to the pi, it has full access control to the pi and you need to type in all the command lines manually.

What I need is for the PC software to 'talk' with the Pi's software and grab certain sensors info on the Pi I2C port (e.g: temperature, humidity). The pi will be able to alert PC software if any of the sensor exceeding threshold (e.g: too humid or too hot)

Comment: Why not just have a noddy program on the Pi whose only function is to send status and I2C readings to the serial link?  It can do that in a loop as slowly or as fast as you want.  If it does unblocking writes it doesn't matter if anything is listening for the data or not.

Comment: I am starting to think that the Pi is technological overkill for this situation. A microcontroller board (such as the Arduino) could most probably do just fine. But even insisting to use a Pi what makes you think that a program cannot send&receive data over the serial link?

Comment: @Ghanima There is other complicated task (which is not related to the current question) the Pi is doing, such as encryption and other processor exhaustive task (and this is why Pi was chosen over Arduino)

Comment: @joan the Pi would also need to receive command through the link instructed by the PC software, e.g: trigger some buzzer or LEDs. Would your method able to fullfill this requirement?

Comment: Yes.  You could leave what I suggested as is on the Pi out side.  Another, or the same program could also be looping just reading serial inputs.  You need to write down the data and alerts you want to receive from the Pi and the commands you want to send to the Pi.  It may be the sort of program people write in languages like Python.

Comment: @joan, do you have any example link i can refer to on coding the 'serial software' in the Pi?

Answer (score 2):

An USB Null Modem Cable could work. It's for USB-host to another USB-host. Each end appear as a (fast) serial port to respective host.
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_USBNMC.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can go for a Bluetooth connection.
There are cheap BT dongles for your RPi out there ([quick installation tutorial](http://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-raspberry-pi-nano-bluetooth-dongle))
and then use rfcomm to interact with your RPi.