# What's the smartest way to send data from my pi to my PC?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, usb, data-transfer, pi-1

Here's the deal: I've connected a small RFID reader module (RDM6300) to my Raspberry Pi 1 Model B. That means I've taken up one 5V pin, one ground pin and one RX pin. A python script reads my RFID tag and prints out the result of the reading. This result needs to be sent to my computer.

Transmission via ethernet (connecting the Pi *directly* to PC) is not a possibility unfortunately, as the ethernet port of my PC is already in use. 
I also cannot integrate the Pi into my network and access it this way.

I've thought about connecting to my PC via USB using [this cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954). The only problem with this solution is I'm already using the RX pin (my RFID module is connected to it).

Is there a way I can still connect to my PC? Also, if I am misunderstanding anything here, please let me know.

Comment: why you want to connect that way. Here how i did, i connected my PI in my local network and i access my PI.

Comment: Why don't you connect RDM6300 directly to the PC using that cable you've found? I bet your PC is capable of running Python.

Comment: create a python script that outputs sound waves. Than convert the data to binary, and send it out through the jack output. Now create a python script that listens t othe PCs microphone port and interpret the data. That will only cost you 1 dollar for that jack cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your raspberry-pi as access point and connect your pc with it using wifi. Then you can send data from raspberry-pi to your pc using some software.

Here are some links for your help:

https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview

https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to transmit from the Pi to the PC and don't need to receive anything back, you don't need to use the Pi's RX pin. Just connect the appropriate pins of that adapter to the Pi's TX and GND.

The above should be fine unless it's absolutely critical that each message gets through correctly, in which case you'd want to implement a protocol in which the PC can confirm back to the Pi that it has received the message (using some sort of error checking like a CRC).

If your Pi has a spare USB port, you can use a USB-serial adapter on the Pi *and* one on the PC, and connect RX on one adapter to TX on the other and vice versa (and connect both grounds together). That might work OK with two of those adapters, but it would definitely work with two USB to 9-pin RS-232 adapters and a null modem cable in between them - you could then use hardware handshaking to make sure each device only sends data when the other one is ready to receive it.

Another option would be to use a USB-ethernet adapter on your PC, giving it a second network port which you could cable the Pi to.

There are some further options in the answers to [this question.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29234/data-collection-from-raspberry-pi-and-send-to-computer-without-using-ethernet-o?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple 5 port ethernet switch would be a simple relatively inexpensive hardware solution.

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=5+port+ethernet+switch

Answer (score 0):

Here my experience of reading Wiegand reader (RFID) and based on the value of the card or tag I am allowing mu door to open. I have developed an Access control system using Raspberry PI, python and Python Flask REST API.

I dont know this will help you or not. But what I am doing is I have used a wireless module connected to my ethernet port of the Raspberry PI. And that wireless adapter connected to my local wifi. The wireless adapter connected with Raspberry PI is fully configurable and you can connect to your wifi.

After connection i normally do ssh to the pi and write code and upload the python scripts to read values from reader and store that values to local sqlite3 db file. I have stored the authorized cards into a file in Raspberry using my central REST api calling from a python script on that raspberry.

see this product to connect your local network via wifi: [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N0GKZS9)

if you are interested, I can post my codes how I send my rfid data to my central DB (in my pc) from Raspberry PI. But you need to have good knowledge in HTTP and REST APIs.